# AndroidStudio EditText can't be edited (cursor disappear)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having a weird problem i've never encountered.

I'm building a layout for an activity. My only issue is, i can't edit the edittexts in any way. I've tried both with the emulator and the real device. To be more specific, when i click on the edittext, the cursor appears for a very short moment, then disappears. The keyboard shows up but get stuck and doesn't work. In the java code only enable / disable the the editext :

```java
          @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(bottlename.isEnabled()){
                    //bottlenumber.setEnabled(false);
                    ArrayList<Bottle> bottle = BottleView.getBottlelist();
                    bottle.set(Integer.parseInt(bottlenumber.getText().toString())-1, new Bottle(bottlename.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(bottlenumber.getText().toString()), R.drawable.vodka));
                    bottlename.setEnabled(false);
                }else{
                    bottlename.setEnabled(true);
                    //bottlenumber.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

I've already tried many solutions from other posts, with no luck.

Attaching the xml code here:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottleimage"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/bottlename"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:text="Bottle"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/bottlenumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="X"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/editbottle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: on what view have you set your `onClickListener` ? Also note that once your `edittext` is set enabled as `false` then you won't be getting any `onClickEvent` on that means it would be set as `false` until you make it `true` in any other way

Answer (score 0):

Is all your EditText fields disabled (android:enabled="false") in your layout intentionally?

Comment: Yes, default I want my editext disabled and when I click on an buttonimage I want to enable it

Comment: Can you provide full activity code that uses this handler?

Answer (score 0):

the behavior it's a bit weird, I suggest to move the action of reading the value of the editText to a button, so you will have to change the text of the button like this :

- When EditTexts enabled ==> "Send"
- When EditTexts disabled ==> "Enable"

Comment: Okay, but it's not solving my issue